# Unity 3D Tilemap.GetInstantiatedObject null on Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a script to fill a hexadecimal tilemap.
Here is a light version of this script:

```
[SerializeField]
private Tilemap Board_Tilemap;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject TilePrefab;

void Start()
{
    var tileObject = new Tile
    {
        gameObject = TilePrefab
    };
    Board_Tilemap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(0, 0, 0), tileObject);      
    Board_Tilemap.GetInstantiatedObject(new Vector3Int(0, 0, 0)).GetComponent<Renderer>().material = Resources.Load<Material>($"Materials/{tile.Value.MaterialName}");  
}
```

This work perfectly, tiles are at the right position, with the right rotation and right material.
But strangely when I try to get the instantiated object during update to make it like a tile flip but the method GetInstantiatedObject returns null:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3Int tilemapPos = Board_Tilemap.WorldToCell(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        var boardTilePos = new Vector3Int(tilemapPos.x, tilemapPos.y, 0);

        Board_Tilemap.GetInstantiatedObject(boardTilePos).transform.Rotate(90, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the null variable? To discover: Vector3Int tilemapPos = Board_Tilemap.WorldToCell(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)); print(tilemapPos);
        var boardTilePos = new Vector3Int(tilemapPos.x, tilemapPos.y, 0);  print(boardTilePos);
        Board_Tilemap.GetInstantiatedObject(boardTilePos).transform.Rotate(90, 0, 0); print(“End”);

Comment: Board_Tilemap.GetInstantiatedObject(boardTilePos) this part returns null